# How to find sentence with Notepad++ Regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find the sentence that starts with some word and end with some word.
For example the sentence that starts with "Hello" and ends with goodbye "Helloxxxxxxxgoodbye"

Comment: This is regex 101, please consider following a regex tutorial which will teach you how to do this and much more in less than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.*` to match all characters, so to find something starting with Hello and ending in goodbye would be `/Hello.*goodbye/`.

A good website to test regex is https://regex101.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the `/pattern/` syntax is specific to a few languages (javascript at least) and won't work in Notepad++ where the slashes would be matched as literal characters.

Comment: Besides, `a*.b` only matches a substring from the first `a` to to the last `b`  on a line and does not really match any start and end of *sentences*.